# Using cordova, can I use resolveLocalFileSystemURL to access a file that was in my build?

Tags: javascript, xcode, cordova

I'm building an app where I need to copy some pdfs that were inside my www folder to the shared device folder (`FileEntry.toURL`) but I'm not sure where to access these pdfs after my app is on the device.

If I use `resolveLocalFileSystemURL`, I can specify a file path and then copy that found file to the `FileEntry.toURL()` folder... but I'm not sure what that file path would be.

My file is located `www/media/pdf/TestDocument.pdf` - how do I access this file after I have done a build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `1.2.0` of the `file` plugin. Then you should be able to use `cordova.file.applicationDirectory` to get at your bundle.